# modules with several powers $x^{y^z}$

Tags: number-theory, modular-arithmetic, exponentiation, chinese-remainder-theorem

I have an assignment(which gives no credit) which I cant solve so I would like to get some help

$3^{{1001}^{1002}}\pmod {43}$ (All original numbers were replaced)

Our hint was to use the Chinese-remainder-theorem but I don't see how when $43$ is a prim number.

Answer (score 2):

$$3^{1001^{1002}}\equiv3^{1001^{1002}\pmod{\phi(43)}}\pmod{43}$$

Now, $\phi(43)=42=2\cdot3\cdot7;$

As $(1001,42)=7$

let use find $\displaystyle 1001^{1002-1}\pmod{\frac{42}7}$

As $1001\equiv-1\pmod6\implies 1001^{1002-1}\equiv(-1)^{1001}\equiv-1\pmod6$

$\displaystyle\implies1001^{1002}\equiv1001(-1)\pmod{6\cdot1001}\equiv-1001\pmod{42}\equiv7$

Comment: Thanks for your help!
Could you please explain some steps for me?

Why is 3^{1001^{1002}} congruent module with 3^{1001^{1002}mod(42)} mod 43?

Why do you write 1002-1 instead of 1001 (the power is 1002! )?

Comment: @user1991779, If $n=d\cdot\phi(m)+r,(a,m)=1$ $$a^n=a^r(a^{\phi(m)})^d\equiv a^r\cdot1^d\pmod m$$

Comment: I understood you comment, but I still don't understand your solution.
why is gcd(1001,42) useful?

why is
⟹1001^1002≡1001(−1)
true?

Comment: @user1991779, We can apply Fermat, Euler Totient theorem etc. and make some calculations if $(a,m)=1$ that's why the division by gcd$(1001,42)$ .Also find $\#9$ of http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Congruence.html

Answer (score 1):

Changing the numbers is good policy for learning - thank you! - but for this kind of problem you have to be careful, as what appears to be a small or random change may make the problem very much harder.  So I will change the problem again and show you how to solve it, before returning to your problem.

**Problem**.  Simplify $3^{1001^{1002}}\pmod{52}$.

**Solution**.  By trial and error we get modulo $52$
$$3^1=3\,,\ 3^2=9\,,\ 3^3=27\,,\ 3^4=81=29\,,\ 3^5=87=35\,,\ 3^6=105=1\ .$$
So for any $k$ we have
$$3^{6k}=(3^6)^k=1^k=1\pmod{52}\ .$$
We also have
$$1001=-1\pmod6\quad\Rightarrow\quad 1001^{1002}=(-1)^{1002}=1\pmod6$$
and so we can write
$$1001^{1002}=6k+1\ .$$
Therefore we get the simplification
$$3^{1001^{1002}}=3^{6k+1}=(3^6)^k\times3^1=1^k\times3=3\pmod{52}\ .$$

---

For your problem the principle is the same, but unfortunately the trial and error stage does not give $3^n=1\pmod{43}$ until $n=42$, which makes the calculations rather more difficult.

Comment: Very nice and simple solution but I don't think I will apply it on my exam if there are other ways to solve the problem since the trial and error stage is to time consuming.
Thank you!

Comment: Depends on the numbers.  If there is a small power which is congruent to $1$, then this is the best method.

Comment: or you can use the Fermat's little theorem $$ \text{if p is prime and } p \nmid a \text{ then } a^{p-1}\equiv{1\pmod{p}} $$ so in your case $$ 3^{42} \equiv 1 \pmod{43} $$ and finally n=42

Comment: @adam.cajf True, but Fermat does not always give the best possible result.  For example, it also tells you that $4^{42}\equiv1\pmod{43}$, but in fact, $4^7\equiv1$ which is much more helpful.

Comment: Yes, I fully agree. I've just given an alternative if there is no small power congruent to 1.

Answer (score 0):

What do you think about this solution? I think it's a general solution(is it?)

`{2014^{2013}} \equiv 2^{2014mod\phi (41)^{2013} }  \equiv 2^{14^{2013}} \equiv 2^{14^{2013}mod\phi (41)} \equiv 2^{14^{13}} \equiv 2^{(14^{2})^{6}14^{1}} \equiv 2^{36^{6}14^{1}} \equiv 2^{36*14^{1}} \equiv 2^{12*40+24(mod\phi (41))} \equiv 2^{24} \equiv (2^{7})^{3}*2^{3} \equiv (5^{3}*2^{3} \equiv (41*24+16) \equiv 16) (mod4`1)