# Using Fermat's Little Theorem to find remainders

Tags: elementary-number-theory

My professor does not want us to use mods.

Use Fermat's Little Theorem to find the remainder of $12^{7641}$ divided by $7$.

I have $7 \mid \left(\,12^{7} - 12\,\right)$ and that $12^{7651}=\left(\,12^{7}\,\right)^{1093}$
but I'm basically stuck because a remainder of $12^{1093}$ makes no sense.

Comment: Fermat's Little Theorem takes below form since $\gcd(12,7)=1$  : $$12^6 \equiv 1 \pmod 7$$

Comment: And note that $7641 = 6*1273 + 3$

Comment: Related : http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/906762/raising-2-to-the-power-of-2014-2013-modulo-41

Answer (score 0):

By Fermat's Little Theorem we know that $12^6 = 1 \pmod 7$

- Now $7641 =6 \times 1273 + 3$. So that $(12^6)^{1273} = 1^{1273} = 1 \pmod 7$
- hence $12^{7638} = 1 \pmod 7$
- hence $12^{7638} \times 12^3 = 12^3 \pmod 7$
- hence $12^{7641} = 12^3 \pmod 7$

---

Now $12 = 2^2 3$. Hence $12^3 = 2^6 \times 3^3$

- now $2^3 = 1  \pmod 7$
- hence $(2^3)^2 = 1^2 = 1 \pmod 7$ and $3^3 = 6 \pmod 7$
- now we know that $a = b \pmod p$ and $c = d \pmod p$
- then $a \times c = b \times d \pmod p$
- hence $2^6 \times 3^3 = 1 \times 6 \pmod 7$
- hence $12^3 = 6 \pmod 7$
- hence $12^{7641} = 12^3 = 6 \pmod 7$

so the remainder is 6.